# Tornado WebSocket Handler deactivate Nagle's algorithm

Tags: python, tcp, websocket, tornado

To reduce latency for real time websocket-based app, I'm trying to deactivate Nagle's algorithm using Tornado WebSocketHandler written in python.
Documentation says to use this method on connection opening:

```
self.set_nodelay(True)
```

I tried but TCP message are still getting clamped together.

I'm working behind a proxy, is it possible that Nagle is also operating at the proxy level ?

Thanks for you help

Comment: Which version of Tornado are you using, and which operating system?

Comment: I use tornado shipped with Rosbridge Suite which is version 4.0 with Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Which proxy are you working with? Squid/Varnish/nginx?

Comment: It's a corporate proxy, i don't know

Comment: If the path looks like <client> --> <proxy> --> <your_app>, then there isn't much you can do, as you're disabling Nagle's algorithm on the app->proxy socket.

Comment: The path is actually myapp -> proxy -> client

Comment: Of course, it goes both ways :)

Comment: Ok so when behind a proxy, there is nothing you can do to disable Nagle basically

Comment: You can, but since only the proxy will see your packets (assuming it's an application-level proxy, and not an L2 forwarder), then it won't affect the client at all.

Comment: There's nothing else you can do in your app, but the proxy administrator could disable Nagle at that stage. For example, nginx has the `tcp_nodelay` option. Nagle's algorithm needs to be disabled at every stage in the pipeline to have the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

Yes (corporate) proxies will mess up async connections.
One approach would be to use SSL/TLS connections so the proxy can't stick it's nose into the traffic and can't modify it anymore.
But delayed ACKs which is the basis for the Nagle phenomena are issued on the Transport layer, which is beneath the SSL/TLS encryption, so the encryption will not solve delayed ACKs, but it will solve proxy delays due to application layer data manipulation.